# Run my JavaScript code on every page on my browser, similar to how a Chrome extension would

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, userscripts, web-extension

I know with Chrome I can use snippets to manually run some JavaScript code on a webpage. But this required manually executing the snippet. Is there a way to have some JavaScript code that my browser (Chrome or Firefox) would load every time I visit a new page?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Actually the best thing to do is to create a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 8):

You may be looking for [userscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript). These allow you to write JavaScript code which will then be automatically executed whenever you visit a page matching a particular pattern.

For example, the following userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             example name
// @include          /^https://example\.com/
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('Hello, World!');
```

will result in *Hello, World!* being logged to the console every time you visit https://example.com/.

To run userscripts, you need a userscript manager. [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) is the most popular choice - it works for all modern browsers.

Another option is a bookmarklet, which allow you to store code in a browser bookmark, but they require you to click on the bookmark link in order to execute the code - it won't run automatically. For example, a bookmark with the following URL:

```
javascript: (() => {  console.log('Hello, World!') })();
```

will result in *Hello, World!* being logged to the console whenever the bookmarklet is clicked. For any code that isn't trivially short, a userscript is probably the more maintainable choice.

Answer (score 3):

The [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) Chrome and Firefox extension can solve your use case. You can use the [Insert Script feature](https://medium.com/requestly-docs/inserting-scripts-dynamically-in-a-webpage-be4af90da20a) to inject any JavaScript code or CSS code before or after page load.

You can either enter a custom URL for the JavaScript file or write the custom JavaScript code in the inbuilt editor. You can also create a JavaScript/CSS file in [Requestly library](https://app.requestly.in/library) too and use that file.

[image]